# How to recover data from a .docx archive?

Tags: xml, ubuntu, error-handling, zip, docx

I am trying to recover a text from a `.docx` in Ubuntu. My `.docx` is called `i.docx`, and I managed to get the archive `i.zip` from it.

I already tried this following commands in terminal:

1. `zip -FF i.zip --out n.zip`
2. `unzip -vt i.zip`
3. `jar xvf i.zip`

This is what I get for running the first command:

```
 Found end record (EOCDR) - says expect single disk archive
Scanning for entries...
 copying: word/styles.xml  (3817 bytes)
 copying: word/webSettings.xml  (305 bytes)
 copying: word/fontTable.xml  (548 bytes)
 copying: docProps/core.xml  (381 bytes)
 copying: docProps/app.xml  (482 bytes)
Central Directory found...
no local entry: [Content_Types].xml
no local entry: _rels/.rels
no local entry: word/document.xml
no local entry: word/_rels/document.xml.rels
no local entry: word/footnotes.xml
no local entry: word/endnotes.xml
no local entry: word/footer1.xml
no local entry: word/theme/theme1.xml
no local entry: word/settings.xml
no local entry: word/numbering.xml
EOCDR found ( 1  23671)...
```

And this is what get for running the second command:

```
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  0
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  954
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  1754
file #4:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  8876
file #5:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9495
file #6:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  10190
file #7:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  10882
file #8:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  11729
file #9:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  13526
file #10:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  14985
    testing: word/styles.xml          OK
    testing: word/webSettings.xml     OK
    testing: word/fontTable.xml       OK
    testing: docProps/core.xml        OK
    testing: docProps/app.xml         OK
At least one error was detected in i.zip.
```

And this is what get for running the third command:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:1003)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:468)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.copy(Main.java:1249)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.copy(Main.java:1277)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:1454)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:1395)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:410)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1681)
```

This is as far as I can get, run out of ideas, so any input of how to recover would be much appreciated!